# How can I get the Snow Leopard Terminal app to act like the Leopard Terminal app?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, terminal.app

The delimiters for double-click text selection in the Leopard Terminal app (version 2.0.2) included slash (/) and period (.) -- the delimiters for double-click text selection in the Snow Leopard Terminal app (version 2.1.2) include slash (/) but do not include period (.).

For example, in a Leopard version 2.0.2 Terminal window double-clicking on the "**x**" in "**project/nexus.notes**" selects only "**nexus**" whereas it selects "**nexus.notes**" on a Snow Leopard version 2.1.2 Terminal window.

I found that using shift + command makes version 2.1.2 ignore the slash, thereby selecting all of "**project/nexus.notes**" which is very nice and no doubt useful, but I need to go the other way and respect both the slash and the period, as the Terminal app did on Leopard.

So my question is: does anyone know of a tweak to make version 2.1.2 respect the same delimiters that version 2.0.2 respected?

And my comment is that this seems a rather arbitrary change, so Apple must have left a way to return to the established behavior...  (okay, I'm just kidding)

Thanks,
    Peter

Comment: Not related to system-wide word separators in my testing.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal uses the system-wide word break rules, controlled by System Preferences. You should find that double-click in Terminal behaves the same way in TextEdit and most other applications. There is no available word break setting that behaves the way you desire.

Period "." may sometimes be part of a word and sometimes not. For example, "foo.bar" is one word, but "foo2.bar" is two. The rules are intended for human languages and involve some heuristics that may not always meet user expectations for arbitrary computer data in a terminal. The Snow Leopard rules make it so that domain names (and filenames with extensions) are one word.

(As you noted, Shift-Command-Double-Click selects whole pathnames. It also opens URLs.)